# How to read extra-ASCII characters in R?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I am reading input text file line by line with the following function:

```
lines_reader<-function(filename){
    conn<-file(filename,open="r")
    linn<-readLines(conn,encoding="UCS-2LE")
    close(conn)
    return(linn)
}
```

If I try to plot these lines in the R enviroment, letters with accent marks are treated not adequately appearing like "Ã" or  "Ã¨" instead of "à" or "è".

How to cope with this? What encoding I should choose?

Here they are my session and local system info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0


> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252"
```

Comment: maybe it is a locale problem. Try `Sys.getlocale()` and let us know what is the output.

Comment: Also, what is your OS? Try posting the output of sessionInfo()

Comment: I edited the post with what you asked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the encoding that you are using:

```
lines_reader<-function(filename){
    conn<-file(filename,open="r")
    linn<-readLines(conn,encoding="UTF-8")
    close(conn)
    return(linn)
}
```